# JavaScript invalid input condition

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.Other day I made a game of Rock Paper Scissor.The game works fine but I wanted to know that can you put up a condition that if the User chooses to input invalid choice an alert box appears and says invalid input something like that!
Here is my code!

```
   var userchoice=prompt("Wanna play Rock, Paper and Scissors?");{
    if (userchoice!="paper") {
        alert("Invalid ID");
    }
    else if (userchoice!="scissors") {
        alert("Invalid ID");
    }
    else (userchoice!="rock") {
        alert("Invalid ID");
    }
}
var computerchoice=Math.random();{
    if(computerchoice<0.34){
    console.log(computerchoice="paper");
    }
    else if (computerchoice<=0.67) {
        console.log(computerchoice="rock");
    }
    else{
        console.log(computerchoice="scissors");
    }
};
var compare=function(choice1,choice2){
    if (choice1===choice2){
        console.log("The game was a tie!");
    }
    else if (choice1==="rock") {
        if (choice2==="scissors") {
            console.log("rock wins!");
        }
        else{
            console.log("paper wins!")
        }   
    }
    else if(choice1==="paper"){
        if (choice2==="rock") {
            console.log("paper wins!");
        }
        else{
            console.log("scissors wins!");
        }
    }
    else if (choice1==="scissors") {
        if (choice2==="paper") {
            console.log("scissors wins!")
        }
        else {
            console.log("rock wins!");
        }
    }
};

compare(userchoice,computerchoice);
console.log("User: "+userchoice);
console.log("Computer: "+computerchoice);
//End of Game
```

Comment: Improve your question by explaining what you've tried and how the results differ from what you expected. Showing a long code listing puts the burden on the people that you're hoping will help you.

Comment: `else` can't have a condition (line 8)

Comment: Meaning if any time user tries to input other than "scissor,rock or paper" a alert box appears saying "invalid  input" something like that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some compacted code to figure out if any of the choices are invalid. It alerts if there was an invalid choice, but you should change that to a more appropriate behavior.

```
var VALID_CHOICES = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
var choice1 = 'rock', choice2 = 'something invalid'
var invalidChoice = false
;[choice1, choice2].forEach(function(choice) {
  if (VALID_CHOICES.indexOf(choice) === -1) invalidChoice = true
})
if (invalidChoice) alert('Picked an invalid choice')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Array/indexOf). Try the demo below:

```js
function newGame(msg) {
    var allowed = ["rock","paper","scissors"],
        user = allowed.indexOf(prompt((msg||'Feeling lucky?') + ' Choose "rock", "paper" or "scissors":').trim().toLowerCase()),
        comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

    if(user < 0) return newGame("Invalid ID!");

    console.log("You chose "+ allowed[user] +". Computer chose "+ allowed[comp] +".");

    if(user == comp)
        console.log('The game was a tie!');
    else if([1,-2].indexOf(comp-user) > -1)
        console.log('Computer wins with ' + allowed[comp] + '!');
    else
        console.log('You win with ' + allowed[user] + '!');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newGame()">New game</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function like this, that will prompt, but also will check if the choice is valid.

```js
function ask(q) {
    var choice = prompt(q);
    if (choice != 'scissors' && choice != 'rock' && choice != 'paper') {
        alert('Invalid input. Only "scissors", "rock" or "paper" are allowed.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return choice;
    }
}
console.log('the choice is:',ask("Wanna play Rock, Paper and Scissors?"));
```

The `if` checks if the choice is not `"scissors"` or `"rock" or`"paper", if is invalid it will alert, and return false.
But if the choice is valid it will return `choice`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can keep `compare` the way you defined it.
- `trim()` removes white spaces before and after user answer
- `toLowerCase()` converts uppercase letters to lowercase

  ```
  var promptUser = function(text){
    var userAnswer = prompt(text);
    var cleanAnswer = userAnswer.trim().toLowerCase();
    if(['paper', 'scissors', 'rock'].indexOf(cleanAnswer) === -1) {
      alert('Invalid choice: ' + cleanAnswer);
    }
    return cleanAnswer;
  }

  var computerPlays = function() {
    var computerchoice = Math.random();
    if(computerchoice<0.34){
      computerchoice="paper";
    } else if (computerchoice<=0.67) {
      computerchoice="rock";
    } else {
      computerchoice="scissors";
    }
    return computerchoice;
  };

  var userChoice = promptUser("Wanna play Rock, Paper and Scissors?");
  var computerChoice = computerPlays();
  console.log('user picks:', userChoice);
  console.log('computer picks:', computerChoice)
  compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
  ```